# AngularJS: Conditional Chaining with JSON Filter

Tags: json, angularjs

I am trying to conditionally display certain fields of JSON objects using filters. Currently it displays something like this:

JSON Ouput:`[
        { tag: "Reading", checked: true },
        { tag: "Writing", checked: false },
        { tag: "Homework", checked: true},
        { tag: "Groupwork", checked: false }
    ];`

Desired output:

`Reading, Homework`

Where I would only display those fields in which checked == true.

HTML/AngularJS:
      `<div class="item">
    <pre ng-bind="tagList | json"></pre>
</div>`

where tagList is the javascript object above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).filter('tagsjson', function(){

    return function(items){

        var arrayToReturn = [];        
        for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
            if (items[i].checked) {
                arrayToReturn.push(items[i].tag);
            }
        }
        return arrayToReturn.join();
    };
});
```

You can then use your filter as:

```
<div class="item">
    <pre ng-bind="tagList | tagsjson"></pre>
</div>
```

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vp5iXxbmTEea8EK1ZQpI) demonstrating the above

PS: you can name your filter json but this will override the built in filter, as you have in your code, not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Without a parameter to `.join()`, you will end up with "ReadingHomework". It should be `.join(', ')`. You should also show how to use your filter.

Comment: Not true. .join() without params returns comma separated string of array value. Check it out: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: Interesting, I stand corrected. I had to confirm using a [reliable documentation site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), but you are correct. Though the OP did say they wanted them joined by ", ". Also, I wouldn't ever advocate overriding the default filter names, that will be a nightmare for any other developer on the project.